# Run NAS in VMWare ESXi to share datastore

Tags: nas, esxi, plex, vmware-server

Is there any official NAS software to be run inside VMWare ESXi to use datastore as a NAS withalong Plex?

Comment: I don't see any reason that, Any OS you would run on a physical machine, could not instead be ran inside a VM.  I have in the past setup Samba configuration on a ESXi backbone.

Comment: I was hoping there was just a plugin rather than running a whole VM

Comment: The easiest way would be to setup a separate VM. That's how I am running Plex in my lab. Separate Linux VM as a NAS and another Linux VM serves Plex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can virtualize TrueNAS https://www.truenas.com/ which is a free Open-Source NAS solution. Within TrueNAS you have multiple options for file sharing:

TrueNAS Sharing Documentation:

> File sharing is a core benefit of a NAS. TrueNAS helps foster collaboration between users through network shares.
> TrueNAS can use AFP, iSCSI shares, Unix NFS shares, Windows SMB shares, and WebDAV shares.

NFS is a easy solution to use when setting up a datastore in ESXi:

> Procedure:
> Click Storage in the VMware Host Client inventory and click Datastores.
> Click New datastore.
> The New datastore wizard opens.
> On the Select creation type page, click Mount NFS datastore and click Next.
> On the Provide NFS mount details page, provide the details for the NFS you mount.
> Enter a name for the NFS datastore.
> Enter the NFS server name.
> For the server name, you can enter an IP address, a DNS name, or an NFS UUID.

From there you can store all your media inside of the datastore.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know that TrueNAS and FreeNAS unified